# Tag Synonym Request: stovetop, percolator -> moka

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

Current we have [stovetop](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stovetop) (1), [percolator](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/percolator) (1), and [moka](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moka) (2). These are all different words for the same thing, and we should unify them into a single tag. So:

1. What tag do we pick for this?
2. Once we've decided, can synonyms be created from the other two.

Comment: I call moka and percolator rather different devices, brewing methods, and outcomes. I wonder if this is a regional terminology difference. See [my thoughts](http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/a/74/262) below. Let's have a [discussion] first :).

Comment: May I also suggest that you change the title to something referencing the tag you're trying to synonymise? E.g., it's currently "Tag Synonym Request" to something like "Tag Synonym Request: stovetop, percolator, moka" such as [this one](http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/68/potential-tag-synonyms-flavor-flavour-coffee-taste). I would suggest this as an edit directly, but the link is cold; looks like we only have the [1000+rep edit](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/help/editing) so far.

Comment: @hoc_age Done :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I call moka and percolator very different things; I think [moka] and [percolator] should remain separate and distinct.

[Moka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moka_pot) is what some call a stovetop espresso maker, which I think is a misnomer anyway.  But it uses pressure to force water through grounds.  Water goes through the grounds (which are in the middle of the device) once into a storage vessel on top, which is separate from the chamber in which the water was added at the beginning of the brew.

But I call [percolator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee_percolator) something that boils water and drips it over grounds repeatedly.  There is no separate storage vessel for the coffee once brewed; water (at first) or (partially-brewed) coffee is repeatedly boiled and dripped over the grounds (which are instead at the top of the chamber).  The brewed coffee ends up where the plain water was at the beginning of the brew.

I have both devices, and use them differently; e.g., a coarser grind for percolator.  I find the outcome of percolated coffee to be more like French press or perhaps drip; moka is more like Turkish coffee or espresso. Though similar in concept, they're (to me) totally different in outcome.

Is this a regional terminology difference?  Am I splitting hairs, or have I been doing this wrong all the years?? :)

I agree to drop "stovetop" as it's ambiguous.

Comment: You're right, I didn't know percolators were different from mokas. This is interesting as both are 'stovetops', so a simple tag synonym won't do here I don't think...

Comment: @fredley - I migrated this to a [question](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/418/262) and [self-answer](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/419/262) to expand the conversation; perhaps my distinction is not common? /me tries not to be self-conscious :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest we use [moka](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moka) as the tag. Not only is it what the people who invented it call it, but it's the most popular term according to [Google Trends](https://www.google.co.uk/trends/explore#q=moka%2C%20percolator%2C%20stovetop):

[image]

Comment: Agreed, it is also the wiki article name: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moka_pot

Comment: "moka" could be confused with a "mocha coffee". Maybe the tag should be "moka-pot".

Comment: @vclaw Hmm, I'd rather stick with the shorter tag (since it's correct). If anyone gets them confused I'm sure the community will step in to correct the error!